# JBPM stable version for production use?

Tags: java, jbpm, business-process-management

I am working on building a workflow application and I'm planning to use JBPM as my BPM framework. Can anyone suggest me which is the stable version to use in producation environment?

Comment: Any reason to believe the latest (6.5.0.Final as of right now) is not stable / production ready?

Comment: here is one such reason..  https://developer.jboss.org/thread/267687. I'm having trouble in using user task, getting null pointer exception upon task completion. Apparently, I'm not the only one who encountered this issue.

Comment: If you wait until there are no bugs at all, you'll never go to production.

Comment: Yeah I know that dude. Alright, I am going to use 6.5.0.Final for my project as this is the only latest stable release available as now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with enterprise release of jBPM which is Red Hat JBoss BPMS. Red Hat will provide hot-fix patches to known issues. Also rollup patches are provided on certain interval, which includes fix for multiple issues. Along with all this you will get 24x7 support for issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just let you know, I have been using jbpm 6.5  with docker in production for 2 months. All work smoothly